Failed Deleted Image Uploads from bot
I have a discord bot that works on discord.js v13. It's purpose is to upload deleted images/videos in a server to another server's logging channel. It used to work perfectly fine until recently, it started failing uploads Image showing failed upload
It doesn't do this with all the images but most of the images or videos. It started doing this around 23rd May.
Does anyone have any idea what could be the reason or if Discord made any change to how attachments are handled?
I checked the same code with the test bot (where I check the code before releasing on the main bot) but it also faced same problem.

As mentioned here

if no one (besides Discord itself) viewed/requested the image, e.g. via a web browser, then when the message that the image is attached to is deleted, Discord's CDN will restrict access to the image.

Not all images can be uploaded by their url if they have been deleted.
The only solution would be to listen for the "messageDelete" event, which includes message attachments
But as stated by sluuuudge here

If the bot client was restarted between the message being sent and deleted, then it won’t be cached.

You would have to fetch all guild messages after every bot restart, which is "API intensive"
